# Appium for iOS device testing

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, instruments, appium

I would like to know if it's possible to execute a touch on the iOS device, such as input events like "tap", "swipe", "drag", "flick" in similar manner of adb shell for android devices using Appium or any other tool. For example, I would like to execute a touch on any icon (such as settings, or some other icon of the main menu). I am not interested to debug my apps, but only to emulate an event in order to debug the device.